# problem with setting rectangle width in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

I have a rectangle that I've created and set its individual properties like so

```
var aRect:Rect = new Rect(); 
aRect.width = "15%";
aRect.height = "15%";
```

Problem is the compiler chokes on `15%` and `"15%"`, with or without the quotes, neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the `15%` thing, [try this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentHeight):

```
aRect.percentWidth = 15;
aRect.percentHeight = 15;
```

See what happens and we can go from there. Are you sure that adding the rect as a child is 'not working'? Is it just not visible? Where is this code exactly? If it doesn't compile with the `15%` thing then how are you even testing the `addChild` code?

Comment: Thanks. I will choose this answer, and open another question to be fair.